# Vlookup alternative value if the initial value is missing

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have created a macro with vlookups which works great. However, now I need to add a different type of vlookup to the formula of column J. I want it to vlookup a different value, if the initial vlookup is not existent. The initial vlookup is

```
With Range("J2:J" & LastRow)
.Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2&""B2"",MARM!A:G,7,0)),"""",IF(VLOOKUP(A2&""B2"",MARM!A:G,7,0)=0,"""",VLOOKUP(A2&""B2"",MARM!A:G,7,0)))"
.Value = .Value
End With
```

And I want to provide the alternative `VLOOKUP` of

```
VLOOKUP(A2&""P2"",MARM!A:G,7,0)
```

So, if the vlookup with B2 ending does not exist, then vlookup with P2 ending.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean you want to use the alternative lookup if the VLOOKUP based on B2 returns an error?

If so, your formula already tests for whether the VLOOKUP based on B2 returns an error and gives the nullstring as the result.

So just replace the nullstring `"""""` with your alternative VLOOKUP:

```
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2&""P2"",MARM!A:G,7,0),"""")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.. which of the two """" should I replace??

Comment: The first one.... it's the one in the IF TRUE section of the IF function that tested whether the B2 VLOOKUP returns an error. It's generally easier to update the formula in the spreadsheet first to make sure you understand it and check that it's working before updating VBA.

Comment: the solution you proposed works fine, but isnt it possible to tell it to leave the cell empty if there is an error.?. Because like this, if the second vlookup is also an error, the cells show N/A or 0. So, I would prefer if the type of formula provided the opportunity to replace error cells with empty cells. You think it is possible?

Comment: Yes, instead of just putting in the VLOOKUP function by itself, put it inside an IFERROR function to return nullstring if that VLOOKUP is also an error.

Comment: I know I am a bit annoying but can you provide this line of code because I will get lost and mess up the code!!!

Comment: You've been shown this already in a previous question. Stack Overflow is meant to help you learn, not just drip feed you pieces of your work until it is complete. Please make an attempt to learn from advice provided and apply it yourself. I've updated my answer this time, but please make more effort to understand and apply advice that has already been provided.